# VBA code to divide cells if reference cell contain a text

Tags: string, vba, text

I need to get a VBA code to excel for following criteria.

If any cell in the range of B1 to B500 contains "TOTAL:", divide same row value in column V with same row value in Column P where "TOTAL:" text exists.

Answer should be in same row column M.

I tried to develop the code like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If r.Value Like "TOTAL:" Then
            With Range("M1:M10")
                r.Formula = "=V5/P1"
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have been your personal efforts so far? Can you provide some code you made yourself?

Comment: I tried to develop the code like this.                                                       Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If r.Value Like "TOTAL:" Then
            With Range("M1:M10")
                r.Formula = "=V5/P1"
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Comment: Please add this to your question and format it with the code-tags. What challenges are you facing exactly?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here:           `With Range("M1:M10")
                r.Formula = "=V5/P1"
            End With` ? Do you just want to divide the values or write a formula? In which cell shall the result be written in to?

Comment: Thanks for your help Klaster. I need to get a value on column M with the same row where "TOTAL:" text exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn VBA, I'd recommend you to solve those problems on your own by searching for 'loop through range' and 'compare string' and so on. That would be much more valuable for you on a long-term.

Anyway, for now you can try this. Please note that it doesn't provide any error handling etc...

Search Range:

`For row = 1 To Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row` loops through the rows from 1 to the last row with a value in column B. If you, for some reason, want to exclude just that very last row and stop at the second last, just substract `1` from it. If you seriously want a fixed range, change the whole thing to `For row = 1 To 500`.

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim row As Long

Set ws = Sheet1    'insert name of sheet

For row = 1 To Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
    If StrComp(Cells(row, 2).Value, "TOTAL:", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Cells(row, 13).Value = Cells(row, 22).Value / Cells(row, 16).Value
    End If
Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks once again for your help Klaster. I calculated column totals at the last row but that row number may varied according to the data available. Because of that I need to keep a range from row 1 to row 500. Then "TOTAL:" string will be in column B (within the range of B1:B500).  Then if "TOTAL:" present value in V column and same row has to be divided by value in column P, same row. That is my requirement. Please check it.

Comment: Hey Ajith, this is pretty straight forward. If you try to understand that piece of code above, you can easily adopt it yourself. I added some explanation.

Comment: One suggestion @Klaster, replace ActiveSheet with a reference to the sheet itself. Using ActiveSheet can cause problems if you inadvertently switch tabs, etc.

Comment: Thanks Klaster. I will try.

Comment: @AMR Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @AjithAbe: if you run into any more troubles related to this, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot Klaster. I got it.

Comment: Nice! Please accept the answer by clicking the tickmark next to my answer to close this question.